# React not rendering passed in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial on React.js, making a Todo app as an example.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TodoItem from "./components/TodoItem";
import Data from "./Data";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { todos:[Data] }
    }
    render() {
        const TodoItems = this.state.todos.map(item =>
            <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} />)
        return (
            <div>
                {todoItems}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

**TodoItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';

function TodoItem (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={props.item.completed} />
            <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
export default TodoItem;
```

Data.js is simply just an array

```
const Data = [{id: 1, text: "Some random text", completed: true}, //and so on... ]
```

When I run this, the browser only renders a checkbox, nothing else. Is there something I'm missing? I checked the dev tools by chrome and saw there are props being passed.

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging. I suggest you also install the React developer tools and learn how to use them. They are very helpful in tracking down problems in a react app.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this: `this.state = { todos:[Data] }`

That doesn't put the contents of `Data` in `todos`, like I think you intend to do, it makes `todos` an array containing `Data`, which itself is an array, i.e:

`todos = [ [ {id: 1, text: "Some random text", completed: true}, ... ] ]`

So when you map over `this.state.todos`, the '`item`' you pull out is actually the single item within `todos` which is in fact the whole `Data` array! (**not** the items within `Data` like you want)

The array has no `text` property, so no text shows. It *also* of course has no `completed` property, but the checkbox does not need that property to exist to get rendered, so you just see one, single, checkbox with no text.

Change it to this, and it should work.

`this.state = { todos: Data }`

An unrelated thing, sure just a copy/paste typo in the code here, but just for completeness, you have `const TodoItems = ...` but then reference `{todoItems}` in the JSX. I guess that should be `const todoItems = ...`.

Comment: Since `[ ...Data ]` is a shallow copy, you will still have problems if any other file sets attributes in an object in the array.

Comment: Ah, good catch, very true. I'll just take that bit out. Don't think it's in scope to start talking about deep cloning arrays of objects for a tutorial example to learn React!

Answer (score -1):

First and the foremost thing is that, you need to export data from the `Data.js` file. Secondly, how you have shown your `Data` variable, i'm assuming it is an array and thus you can set it directly in the state without encapsulating it in squared brackets.

I have also updated the `TodoItem` to make sure the text is inline with the checkbox.
Check out the code sandbox link below!

[image: Edit musing-sutherland-g3snt]